# Read all classes decorated with a particular annotation at runtime

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, cdi

I am required to read all classes(interfaces) decorated with a particular annotation (say @HttpSecurity) at runtime. After scanning through, I wish to read and parse the fields(enum fields) of class decorated with annotations. For eg.

```
@HttpSecurity
public interface MyHttpSecurityConfig {

public enum secure {
    @Path(pathGroup = "/*", pathName = "")
    @Authc
    @Form(errorPage = "/error.html", loginPage = "/login.html", restoreOriginalRequest = "")
    @Authz
    @AllowedRoles(roles = { "roleA", "roleB" })
    @AllowedGroups(groups = { "groupA" })
    @AllowedRealms(realms = { "realmA" })
    @Expressions(expressions = { "#{identity.isLoggedIn()}" })
    Admin
  }
}
```

There might be one or more classes/interfaces decorated with @HttpSecurity. **My first requirement is to fetch all such classes** and second requirement is to build up HttpSecurityBuilder by reading the annotations and their values decorated on enum field(s).
The second requirement is fine and can be done away using reflections. But, **my problem is the first requirement**. I want to achieve first requirement with JavaSE core i.e., without using any external dependency like google reflections. It might be assumed,if necessary, that we have the package name in which classes are to be scanned. Here is what I did usiNG [cdi](https://gist.github.com/girirajsharma/9f227c7fe3d238d832be#file-annotation_configuration-java-L295)

Comment: This has 'terrible idea' written all over it.  Looking at your example, there are existing frameworks to do HTTP web apps, look at EJB 3.0.  With out knowing more about the context of your requirement, it's hard to say how to actually do this.  What kind of app, how is it launched, what kind of performance is required, etc.  Need to know.

Comment: I am trying to provide annotations based configuration to my HTTP Security API.I have tried with CDI extension @observes and with Google reflections library. Google reflections somewhat solve my problem but I don't wish to use any external dependency, but, just the pure SE. Here is what I did using CDI. [Link](https://gist.github.com/girirajsharma/9f227c7fe3d238d832be)

Comment: Have you [looked at EJB security?](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E13981_01/servsecr004.htm)

Comment: @markspace My code is a part of very large framework. EJB Security makes use of its own defined annotations. I am trying to use my own set of annotations. The annotaton based configuration involves lot many other annotations. The code above mentions only a few of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a CDI Extension that observes the scan from CDI Annotations and create you customization, as the example below:

1) You need to create a [Qualifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbck.html), by using you @HttpSecurity

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER})
public @interface HttpSecurity {}
```

2) You need to create a extension by implementing the interface **javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Extension**:

```
    package net.mperon.cdi.extension;

    public class MyExtension implements Extension {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyExtension.class);

    public <T> void processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<T> pat) {
        AnnotatedType<T> at = pat.getAnnotatedType();

        //if dont have you anotation, just continue
        if(!at.isAnnotationPresent(HttpSecurity.class)) {
            return;
        }

        //here you can read all annotation from object and do whatever you want:
        log.info("class: {}", at.getJavaClass());
        log.info("constructors: {}", at.getConstructors());
        log.info("fields: {}", at.getFields());
        log.info("methods: {}", at.getMethods());

        //and so more...

    }
```

}

3) You can see all methods and properties [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/AnnotatedType.html)

4) At last you need to create a service file, under *META-INF/services* named **javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Extension**

5) Inside this text file, you need to put you extension full class name, by example:

```
net.mperon.cdi.extension.MyExtension
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this implementation but was missing on step 4 and 5. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Java doesn't provide an easy way to list classes in the "native" JRE. my favourite solution is the Google Reflections library, but if you don't want to use it there are other ways. One way would be to find the jar or jars in question and scan them for annotations on class files. This is achieved as follows:

```
// Jars are really just zip files with a different name
ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream("/path/to/jar/file.jar"));

for(ZipEntry entry=zip.getNextEntry(); entry!=null; entry=zip.getNextEntry()) {
    String name = entry.getName();

    // We only want class files
    if(name.endsWith(".class") && !entry.isDirectory()) {

        // Remove the .class extension
        name = name.substring(0, name.length() - 6);

        // Replace the slashes in the path with '.'
        name.replaceAll("/",".");

        // Get the class object so we can use reflection on it
        Class<?> cls = Class.forName(name);
    }        
}
```

Comment: I know about this approach. But, as I have mentioned, I am writing backend module for a quite larger security framework and such an approach would not suffice. Is Google Reflections the only way out ? Can CDI serve the purpose ? [Click Here](https://gist.github.com/girirajsharma/9f227c7fe3d238d832be#file-annotation_configuration-java-L295) to see what I did using CDI.